# Web Scrape, and Save To SQLite DB

Tags: javascript, beginner

Now I am pretty crappy at software architecture. I think I was able to make this relatively concise. Please, any input is helpful!

```
 var cheerio   = require("cheerio"),
        request   = require("request"),
        sqlite3   = require("sqlite3").verbose(),
        colors    = require("colors"),
        fs        = require("fs"),
        fetchPage = require('../common/Utilities').fetchPage();

    function parseDateFromHltvDate(dateString) {
        var regexPattern     = new RegExp(/(\d{1,2})[/](\d{1,2}) (\d{1,2})/);
        var parsedDateString = regexPattern.exec(dateString);
        if (parsedDateString) {
            return parsedDateString[2] + '/' + parsedDateString[1] + '/' + parsedDateString[3];
        }
    }

    var processMatchRow = function ($, db) {
        var regexPattern = new RegExp(/(\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2} \d{2}) (.*?)[(](\d{1,2})[)] (.*?)[(](\d{1,2})[)](cbble|mirage|cache|dust2|inferno|overpass|train|nuke)(.*)(W|L)/g);

        //Getting the url for the invididual match
        $(this).children().each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('href') && $(this).attr('href').indexOf('matchid') > 1) {
                matchUrl = 'http://www.hltv.org' + $(this).attr('href');
            }
        });

        var fullMatchRowText = $(this).text().trim();
        var parsedMatchRow   = regexPattern.exec(fullMatchRowText);

        var matchUrl = undefined;

        if (parsedMatchRow) {

            var date         = parseDateFromHltvDate(parsedMatchRow[1].trim());
            var teamOne      = parsedMatchRow[2].trim();
            var teamOneScore = parsedMatchRow[3].trim();
            var teamTwo      = parsedMatchRow[4].trim();
            var teamTwoScore = parsedMatchRow[5].trim();
            var map          = parsedMatchRow[6].trim();
            var event        = parsedMatchRow[7].trim().replace('_ce', '').replace('_se', '');
            var outcome      = parsedMatchRow[8].trim();

            //If Outcome is W then TeamOne wins, else TeamTwo.
            if (outcome.toLowerCase() === "w") {
                outcome = teamOne
            } else {
                outcome = teamTwo
            }
            var value = [matchUrl, date, teamOne, teamOneScore, teamTwo, teamTwoScore, map, event, outcome];

            if (verifyValuesToInsert(value)) {
                updateTeamHistoryRow(db, value);
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to verify values. NOT INSERTING!'.red);
            }
        }
    };

    var verifyValuesToInsert = function (value) {
        var goodToUpdate = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i] === undefined) {
                goodToUpdate = false;
                //console.log('Failed to verify value ' + i + ' @ verifyValuesToInsert!: ' + value.yellow)
            }
        }
        return goodToUpdate;
    };

    function createUniqueHash(values) {
        return JSON.stringify(values);
    }

    function updateTeamHistoryRow(db, value) {

        //Generate a unique hash to identify the row
        var hashValue = createUniqueHash(value);

        //Now add hashValue to the array of 'value'
        value.push(hashValue);

        // Insert some data.

        var statement = db.prepare("INSERT INTO TeamHistory (MatchUrl, Date, TeamOne, TeamOneScore, TeamTwo, TeamTwoScore, Map, Event, Outcome, UniqueHash) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
            [value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4], value[5], value[6], value[7], value[8], value[9]],
            function (err, row) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
            }
        );
        //console.log(statement);
        statement.run(value,
            function (err, row) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
            });
        statement.finalize();
    }

    var getTeamUrls = function () {
        var fTeamUrls = fs.readFileSync('./teamUrls.json').toString();
        return JSON.parse(fTeamUrls);
    };

    function ProcessPage(teamUrl, db) {

        var styles = {
            'matchRowOdd': 'width:606px;height:22px;background-color:white',
            'matchRowEven': 'width:606px;height:22px;background-color:#E6E5E5',
            'date': 'width:10%;float:left;',
            'teamOne': 'width:23%;float:left;font-weight:normal;',
            'teamTwo': 'width:23%;float:left;font-weight:normal;'
        };
        // Use request to read in pages.
        console.log(('Processing ' + teamUrl).blue);
        fetchPage(teamUrl, function (body) {
            // Use cheerio to find things in the page with css selectors.
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            var isStyleMatch = function (elem, style) {
                if ($(elem).attr('style')) {
                    return $(elem).attr('style').indexOf(style) > -1
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            var matchHistoryWrapper = $('#back div.mainAreaNoHeadline div.centerNoHeadline div div.covMainBoxContent div').each(function () {
                //Determine if this is the match URL
                var elementChildren = $(this).children().each(function () {
                    if (isStyleMatch(this, styles.teamRowOdd) || isStyleMatch(this, styles.teamRowEven)) {
                        var childrenofChildren = $(this).children().each(function () {
                                processMatchRow.call(this, $, db);
                            }
                        )
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    }

    exports.GetTeamUrls = function () {
        return getTeamUrls();
    };

    exports.ProcessPage = function (teamUrl, db) {
        return ProcessPage(teamUrl, db);
    };
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. A description of your code would be helpful to other reviewers.